# Where is the upstream source repository for keyboard layouts used in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard-layout, source-code, upstream

I am aware keyboard layouts in Ubuntu are set in two different places: `keyboard-configuration`/`keyboard-setup` take effect only on ttys and the logon screen (at a minimum in MATE, not sure about other flavors), and there is a GUI in system settings which affects only the desktop session.

Where can I find the upstream source repositories for the keyboard layouts used (both tty and desktop session) in Ubuntu? If there are differences between versions and flavors, I am specifically interested in Ubuntu MATE 20.04. Right now I don’t even know which packages (or even files on my local systems) to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per `/usr/share/doc/keyboard-configuration/README.Debian`:

> In Debian the default keyboard layout is shared between the console and X.  It is specified in `/etc/default/keyboard`.

The comments in `/etc/default/keyboard` (where the keyboard layout for tty is configured) state:

> If you don't want to use the XKB layout on the console, you can specify an alternative keymap.  Make sure it will be accessible before /usr is mounted.

There are some layout-related files in `/etc/console-setup/*.kmap.gz`. Their names start with `cached`, and the timestamp indicates that they are likely auto-generated when setting the keyboard layout. So non-XKB layouts seem to have no practical relevance, at least on a system with a GUI (not 100% sure about console-only systems; feel free to add that information if you have it).

**In short, the keyboard layout files for tty and GUI are the same.**

The actual keyboard layouts and related files are stored in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/`. The `symbols` dir holds the key mappings (i.e. which physical key generates which character when pressed, alone or with modifiers), and `rules/evedv.xml` appears to be the map of keyboard layouts.

The source code is at https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config.

Comment: Addition, MATE part is at https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-control-center/tree/master/capplets/keyboard .

Comment: If you are looking for the config UI, then that is the place to go to. What I was looking for is the actual keyboard layouts.